# Ways to avoid eager spool operations on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, spool, eager

I have an ETL process that involves a stored procedure that makes heavy use of `SELECT INTO` statements (minimally logged and therefore faster as they generate less log traffic).  Of the batch of work that takes place in one particular stored the stored procedure several of the most expensive operations are eager spools that appear to just buffer the query results and then copy them into the table just being made.

The MSDN documentation on [eager spools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190435.aspx) is quite sparse. Does anyone have a deeper insight into whether these are really necessary (and under what circumstances)?  I have a few theories that may or may not make sense, but no success in eliminating these from the queries.

The .sqlplan files are quite large (160kb) so I guess it's probably not reasonable to post them directly to a forum.

So, here are some theories that may be amenable to specific answers:

- The query uses some UDFs for data transformation, such as parsing formatted dates. Does this data transformation necessitate the use of eager spools to allocate sensible types (e.g. varchar lengths) to the table before it constructs it?
- As an extension of the question above, does anyone have a deeper view of what does or does not drive this operation in a query?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

My understanding of spooling is that it's a bit of a red herring on your execution plan.  Yes, it accounts for a lot of your query cost, but it's actually an optimization that SQL Server undertakes automatically so that it can avoid costly rescanning.  If you were to avoid spooling, the cost of the execution tree it sits on will go up and almost certainly the cost of the whole query would increase.  I don't have any particular insight into what in particular might cause the database's query optimizer to parse the execution that way, especially without seeing the SQL code, but you're probably better off trusting its behavior.

However, that doesn't mean your execution plan can't be optimized, depending on exactly what you're up to and how volatile your source data is.  When you're doing a `SELECT INTO`, you'll often see spooling items on your execution plan, and it can be related to read isolation.  If it's appropriate for your particular situation, you might try just lowering the transaction isolation level to something less costly, and/or using the `NOLOCK` hint.  I've found in complicated performance-critical queries that `NOLOCK`, if safe and appropriate for your data, can vastly increase the speed of query execution even when there doesn't seem to be any reason it should.

In this situation, if you try `READ UNCOMMITTED` or the `NOLOCK` hint, you may be able to eliminate some of the Spools. (Obviously you don't want to do this if it's likely to land you in an inconsistent state, but everyone's data isolation requirements are different). The `TOP` operator and the `OR` operator can occasionally cause spooling, but I doubt you're doing any of those in an ETL process...

You're right in saying that your UDFs could also be the culprit.  If you're only using each UDF once, it would be an interesting experiment to try putting them inline to see if you get a large performance benefit.  (And if you can't figure out a way to write them inline with the query, that's probably why they might be causing spooling).

One last thing I would look at is that, if you're doing any joins that can be re-ordered, try using a hint to force the join order to happen in what you know to be the most selective order.  That's a bit of a reach but it doesn't hurt to try it if you're already stuck optimizing.

Comment: Read isolation may well be applicable as the process queries from a staging area copied from the source.  Additionally, even if this does not fix my particular issue it adds a bit of insight as this is not mentioned in any of the MSDN literature that I could find concerning eager spool operations.

Comment: I'm glad it was some help.  We might be able to help you further if you posted the SQL code in question (genericized if necessary of course)

Comment: Eager spools are also inferior to lazy spools. I don't have any solid tips for making your eagers turn into lazies, but the concept of working with only a small amount of data at once and putting it all the way through the pipeline suggests an alternate method: Batch your work into smaller pieces of 1000 or 10000 rows at once. It takes quite a bit of work to come up with a good "walking" scheme that lets you quickly step through a clustered index one chunk at a time, but the results can be astounding...

Comment: thank you for mentioning TOP operator here - for me it was the problem in EXISTS clause